# How can I hide badge count number when startForeground()

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, notification-channel

`startForeground()` need to create NotificationChannel so it will show badge number 1 on Launcher icon in Oreo devices

How can I hide/disable it programmatically?

Because Galaxy S8(Oreo) display badge number 1.
And Android 8.0 emulator also display dot.

This is how I am doing now. But `setShowBadge(false)` does not work.

```
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationChannel tmpC = new NotificationChannel(id, "basic", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
        tmpC.setShowBadge(false);

        manager.createNotificationChannel(tmpC);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
                .setChannelId(id)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        startForeground(getPackageName().hashCode(), notification);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, but my client app restarted foreground service whenever app finishes, that was core of the problem, and customers really hate it, because it show badge number 1 whenever close the app, that's how i told them to use remote service for the System.exit for the app.

Comment: Thank you. This is what worked for me: this badge setting cannot be changed without regenerating entirely the NotificationChannel. But even re-compiling the app from Android Studio did not refresh it curiously, however, killing the app and restarting it... did the trick.

Comment: If you really dare the risk of restarting your app, how about using deleteNotificationChannel api?

Comment: Any solution in 2020?

Answer (score 7):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54472640/753575) is correct, but the point is you have to **remove old version of the application by hands** from Android "Applications" menu and install new version with `mChannel.setShowBadge(false)` on the clean device to get it working. An installation over the old version (where `mChannel.setShowBadge(false)` was absent) will not lead to the changing of the behaviour concerned with this badge.

Answer (score 5):

all you need to do is calling `setShowBadge(false)` on your `NotificationChannel` object.

```java
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Create notification channel.
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel({channel_id}, {name}, {importance});
mChannel.setShowBadge(false); // Disable badges for this notification channel.
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

// Create notification and use channel
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, {channel_id})
         ...
         .build();

// notify
mNotificationManager.notify({notification_id}, notification)
```

Check out [Modify a Notification Badge](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#disable).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Example Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN
        );
        serviceChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0 });
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(true);
        serviceChannel.enableLights(false);
        serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);
        serviceChannel.setShowBadge(false); // 
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
```

setShowBadge(false) it is working